# How to loop through objects

Tags: python, django

I'm having a bit of a problem finding a solution to this. I'd like to be able to output some data that I have filtered by datetime, but so that it displays a separate div for each set of objects with a particular date. Is this possible? I couldn't find what would let me do this in the django docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) the sequence based on the date.

Comment: Wow, never knew Django had this..Awesome!